# Simplex Error in R

Tags: r, statistics, mathematical-optimization

Why do I get the following error when I try to solve a minimization problem with the function simplex(boot)?

*Error in simplex1(c(a, rep(0, m1 + 2 * m2 + m3)), cbind(rbind(A1, A2,  :    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length In addition: Warning message: In simplex1(c(a, rep(0, m1 + 2 * m2 + m3)), cbind(rbind(A1, A2,  :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengt*h

```
a <- c(1,0)
A2 <- matrix( c(1, -2.439235,
    1, -2.216999,
    1, -2.069194,
    1, -1.956276,
    1, -1.863888,
    1, -1.785118,
    1, -1.716082,
    1, -1.654373,
    1, -1.598389,
    1, -1.547008) ,10,2,byrow=T )
b2 <- c(5845, 5891, 6684, 6708, 7063, 7508, 7756, 8172, 8188, 8258)
simplex(a=a, A2=A2, b2=b2)
```

Comment: from what package is the function`simplex`?

Comment: yes, boot. 
This function will optimize the linear function a%*%x subject to the constraints A1%*%x <= b1, A2%*%x >= b2, A3%*%x = b3 and x >= 0.

Comment: @Shima: mmh... the dimensions should be ok, so it smells like a bug to me... maybe you should try to contact the boot package maintainer (meanwhile you can use other simplex solvers like lpSolve/glpk etc...)

Comment: @digEmAll: Yes, you are right. I asked the author and he told that it is not intended to be a general-purpose Simplex solver and does crash in certain situations like this. And he told that It is in the boot package to use it at the time for some constrained maximization to the with the saddle-point approximations to the bootstrap distribution.